# Why is my singleton not working as expected?

Tags: node.js, express, redis, mysql2

Am trying to have a single "static" thread for my database in nodejs.
however it just keeps making new instances

```
const mysqlModule = require('mysql2/promise');
const Ioredis = require('ioredis');
const config = require('./config');

class database {
    constructor() {
        if (!database.instance) {
            console.log("Making Database Instance.");
            this.mysql = null;
            this.redis = null;
            this.initialize();
            database.instance = this;
        }
        return database.instance;
    }

    initialize() {
        try {
            console.log("Connecting to DB...");
            this.createMysql();
            this.createRedis();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error initializing database:', error);
            process.exit(1);
        }
    }

    createMysql() {
        this.mysql = mysqlModule.createPool({
            host: config.mysql.host,
            user: config.mysql.user,
            password: config.mysql.pass,
            database: config.mysql.database,
            waitForConnections: true,
            connectionLimit: 10000,
            queueLimit: 0,
            connectTimeout: 15,
            multipleStatements: false
        });
    }

    createRedis() {
        this.redis = new Ioredis({
            host: config.redis.host,
            port: config.redis.port,
        });
    }
}

const db = new database();
module.exports = db;
```

else where i then
const db = require('../../database');
and due to cluster it just connects each core..

and the result is:
Connecting to DB...
Making Database Instance.
Connecting to DB...
Making Database Instance.
Connecting to DB...
Making Database Instance.
Connecting to DB...
Making Database Instance.
Connecting to DB...
Making Database Instance.
Connecting to DB...
Making Database Instance.
Connecting to DB...
Making Database Instance.
Connecting to DB...
Making Database Instance.
Connecting to DB...

What am i doing wrong here?

i tried placing a let instance variable outside the class but that didn't help

Comment: it's required all over the place, just at the top of other files like so:
const db = require('./database');

Comment: This is the correct behaviour. You are creating n processes(number of times you are doing cluster.forks()). Each process will have its own memory space. You cannot share a single connection across multiple processes because of this. But inside a particular process this will be a singleton class.

Comment: is there anyway to share it from the main processes to the cluster instead of having 20+ instances of mysql running?

Comment: No, You cannot share a memory space and that is why you cannot share these connections. Postgres has pgbouncer which does this for you, not sure about mysql. Having 20 open connections for mysql should not be problem, if you manage your instance's connection pool and over all allowed connections to mysql properly.

Comment: if i pass the class on to each fork? will it still create a new instance?